# Problems with obtaining file MIME type in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, mime-types

I am trying to obtain the MIME type of files using `PHP Version 5.2.17` (Linux server).
I have used the following script on another server running `PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny16` (also Linux), and it worked fine:

```
if (in_array(mime_content_type($dir . $img), $image_types)) { ... }
```

Today I tried to use the same on the first server, but it didn't work:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type()
```

So I checked the PHP manual and saw the function `mime_content_type` was deprecated - so I tried this:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if (in_array(finfo_file($finfo, $dir . $img), $image_types)) { ... }
finfo_close($finfo);
```

But, to my surprise:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open()
```

I then checked and noticed that `fifnfo` was only supported as of PHP >= 5.3.0, so this last error makes sense.

I figured maybe the first was set up not to allow any deprecated functions? Is that even possible?

But does that mean there is NO WAY of detecting file MIME types on the server running PHP Version 5.2.17?!
Or is there simply another function to use?

Thank you for any hints!

PS: I am not administrator of either of the two servers.

Comment: @Bojangles thanks a lot! I noticed your solution was `$mime = exec("file -iL $filename 2>/dev/null");`, but i don't undestand quite how it works - could you please clarify? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try using `mime_content_type(filename)` :)

Comment: That's what I tried in the first case, just that the filename argument is being created as a concatenation of two strings - that's not the source of the problem ;)

Comment: oops. Sorry. is the mime module activated on your server?

Comment: That's the thing - not being server adminstrator I don't know

Comment: maybe you can ask the server admin to check if the module is enabled